# VBA remove custom add in tab

Tags: vba, ribbon, office-addins

I found code from Stack Overflow which allowed me to add a custom tab by uploading the xlam file as an add-in (see code below). Unfortunately, the `Deactivate` section doesn't remove the custom tab from the Ribbon when I de-select the add-in from the Developers tab.

I have seen examples where you can hide tabs through `GetVisible`, but I don't know how to incorporate it with the code below. And I haven't found any simpler action which identifies and removes the tab when de-selecting the add-in from the developer tab.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim hFile As Long
    Dim path As String, fileName As String, ribbonXML As String, user As String

    hFile = FreeFile
    user = Environ("Username")
    path = "C:\Users\" & user & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\"
    fileName = "Excel.officeUI"

    ribbonXML = "<mso:customUI       xmlns:mso='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui'>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "  <mso:ribbon>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    <mso:qat/>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    <mso:tabs>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "      <mso:tab id='reportTab' label='Misc' insertBeforeQ='mso:TabFormat'>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        <mso:group id='reportGroup' label='Source Sheet' autoScale='true'>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='runReport' label='Create Sheet' " & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='AppointmentColor3'      onAction='CreateSheet'/>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        </mso:group>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        <mso:group id='Group2' label='Formatting' autoScale='true'>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='FormatButtons' label='Format Selection' " & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='AppointmentColor3'      onAction='Test2'/>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        </mso:group>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "      </mso:tab>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    </mso:tabs>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "  </mso:ribbon>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "</mso:customUI>"

    ribbonXML = Replace(ribbonXML, """", "")

    Open path & fileName For Output Access Write As hFile
    Print #hFile, ribbonXML
    Close hFile

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

    Dim hFile As Long
    Dim path As String, fileName As String, ribbonXML As String, user As String

    hFile = FreeFile
    user = Environ("Username")
    path = "C:\Users\" & user & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\"
    fileName = "Excel.officeUI"

    ribbonXML = "<mso:customUI           xmlns:mso=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"">" & _
    "<mso:ribbon></mso:ribbon></mso:customUI>"

    Open path & fileName For Output Access Write As hFile
    Print #hFile, ribbonXML
    Close hFile

End Sub
```

Comment: *but I don't know how to incorporate it with the code below* - with a callback procedure, exactly like `OnAction`.

Comment: Thank you Mathieu for your response. Do you think you could show me in code how to do this? Ideally I would like the custom tab to be removed from the ribbon when I de-select it from the developer tab. Many thanks!